# C# reading multiple lines into a single variable

Tags: c#, readline

I have looked but failed to find a tutorial that would address my question. Perhaps I didn't word my searches correctly. In any event, I am here.

I have taken over a handyman company and he had about 150 customers. He had a program that he bought that produces records for his customers. I have the records, but he wouldn't sell me the program as it is commercial and he's afraid of going to prison for selling something like that... whatever... They are written in a text file. The format appears to be:

```
string name
string last_job_description
int    job_codes
string job_address
string comments
```

The text file looks like this

```
*Henderson*
*Cleaned gutters, fed the lawn, added mulch to the front flower beds,
 cut the back yard, edged the side walk, pressure washed the driveway*
*04 34 32 1 18 99 32 22 43 72 11 18*
*123 Anywhere ave*
*Ms.always pays cash no tip. Mr. gives you a check but always tips*
```

Alright.. My question is in C# I want to write a program to edit these records, add new customers and delete some I may lose, moves, or dies... But the 2nd entry is broken over two lines, sometimes 3 and 4 lines. They all start and end with *. So, how do I read the 2 to 4 lines and get them into the last_job_description string variable? I can write the class, I can read lines, I can trim away the asterisks. I can find nothing on reading multiple lines into a single variable.

Comment: You must read each line separately and then based on what the first line looks like (if it has enough asterixes) you must decide whether to read the next line and append, or stop. There's no method for textreaders in .NET that read multiple lines, other than ReadToEnd or similar, so you simply have to read the lines yourself, one at a time.

Comment: Or you could see if there is a CSV import library on nuget that can handle newlines in data.

Comment: use File.ReadAllLines

Comment: You can use File.ReadAllText to read the whole file into a `string` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What happens when an `'*'` appears in the text, how is it escaped?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it right!

First define the customer model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastJobDescription { get; set; }
    public List<int> JobCodes { get; set; }
    public string JobAddress { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then, we need a collection of customers:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
```

Fill the collection with data from the file:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("customers.txt");
string pattern = @"(?<= ^ \*) .+? (?= \* \r? $)";

var options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled
    | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline;
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, options);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i += 5)
{
    var customer = new Customer
    {
        Name = matches[i].Value,
        LastJobDescription = matches[i + 1].Value,
        JobCodes = matches[i + 2].Value.Split().Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList(),
        JobAddress = matches[i + 3].Value,
        Comments = matches[i + 4].Value
    };
    customers.Add(customer);
}
```

I'm using a regular expression that allows to have the `*` character in the middle of the lines.

Now we can comfortably work with this collection.

---

Examples of usage.

Remove the first customer:

```
customers.RemoveAt(0);
```

Add a comment to the latest client:

```
customers.Last().Comments += " Very generous.";
```

Find the first record for a client by the name of Henderson and add the code of the job performed:

```
customers.Find(c => c.Name == "Henderson").JobCodes.Add(42);
```

Add new customer:

```
var customer = new Customer
{
    Name = "Chuck Norris",
    LastJobDescription= "Saved the world.",
    JobCodes = new List<int>() { 1 },
    JobAddress = "UN",
    Comments = "Nice guy!"
};
customers.Add(customer);
```

And so on.

---

To save data to a file, use the following:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    sb.Append('*').Append(customer.Name).Append('*').AppendLine();
    sb.Append('*').Append(customer.LastJobDescription).Append('*').AppendLine();
    sb.Append('*').Append(string.Join(" ", customer.JobCodes)).Append('*').AppendLine();
    sb.Append('*').Append(customer.JobAddress).Append('*').AppendLine();
    sb.Append('*').Append(customer.Comments).Append('*').AppendLine();
}
File.WriteAllText("customers.txt", sb.ToString());
```

---

You probably need a graphical user interface. If so, I suggest you to ask a new question where you specify what you use: WinForms, WPF, Web-application or something else.

Comment: You guys should write a tutorial about this. I seriously can't find a lot on it. Microsoft Visual C# 2013 step by step is a horse choking 780 plus pages, and doesn't even mention Trim / Split / or any of this stuff. There is a serious need for this. Maybe do a YouTube video or something. I like all your answers, I didn't have enough rep points to like them all or i would have. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read all the lines in a file into a single variable then you need to do this

`var txt = File.ReadAllText(.. your file location here ..);`

or you can do

`var lines = File.ReadAllLines(.. your file location here);` and then you can iterate through each line and remove the blanks of leave as it is.

But based on your question the first line is what you're really after

Answer (score 0):

when you should read `last_job_description` read second line. if it starts with * it means that this line is `job_codes` otherwise append it to pervous read line. do this fo every lines until you find `job_codes`.

```
using (var fileReader = new StreamReader("someFile"))
        {
            // read some pervous data here

            var last_job_description = fileReader.ReadLine();
            var nextLine = fileReader.ReadLine();
            while (nextLine.StartsWith("*") == false)
            {
                last_job_description += nextLine;
                nextLine = fileReader.ReadLine();
            }
            //you have job_codes in nextline, so parse it now and read next data
        }
```

or you may even use the fact that each set of data starts and ENDS!!! with `*` so you may create function that reads each "set" and returns it as singleline string, no matter how much lines it really was. let's assume that reader variable you pass to this function is the same StreamReader as in upper code

```
function string readSingleValue(StreamReader fileReader){
    var result = "";
    do
    {
        result += fileReader.ReadLine().Trim();
    } while (result.EndsWith("*") == false);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is little complex. What i am trying to say is it doesn't mention to a specific problem. It is contained at least 3 different programming aspects that you need to know or learn to reach your goal. The steps that you must take are described below.

- unfortunately you need to consider your current file as huge string type.
- Then you are able to process this string and separate different parts.
- Next move is defining a neat, reliable and robust XML file which can hold your data.
- Fill your `xml` with your manipulated string.
- If you have a `xml` file you can simply update it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not built-in method that will parse your file exactly like you want, so you have to get your hands dirty.

Here's an example of a working code for your specific case. I assumed you wanted your job_codes in an array since they're multiple integers separated by spaces.

Each time we encounter a line starting with '*', we increase a counter that'll tell us to work with the next of your properties (name, last job description, etc...).

Each line is appended to the current property.

And obviously, we remove the stars from the beginning and ending of every line.

```
string name = String.Empty;
string last_job_description = String.Empty;
int[] job_codes = null;
string job_address = String.Empty;
string comments = String.Empty;

int numberOfPropertiesRead = 0;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:/yourfile.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];
    bool newProp = line.StartsWith("*");
    bool endOfProp = line.EndsWith("*");

    if (newProp)
    {
        numberOfPropertiesRead++;
        line = line.Substring(1);
    }

    if (endOfProp)
        line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);

    switch (numberOfPropertiesRead)
    {
        case 1: name += line; break;
        case 2: last_job_description += line; break;
        case 3:
            job_codes = line.Split(' ').Select(el => Int32.Parse(el)).ToArray();
            break;
        case 4: job_address += line; break;
        case 5: comments += line; break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Wow, that's too many properties dude.");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("name: " + name);
Console.WriteLine("last_job_description: " + last_job_description);
foreach (int job_code in job_codes)
    Console.Write(job_code + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("job_address: " + job_address);
Console.WriteLine("comments: " + comments);
Console.ReadLine();
```